# The decimal zip of two non-negative integers A and B is an integer C in Scala Programming

Tags: algorithm, scala

The decimal zip of two non-negative integers A and B is an integer C whose 
 decimal representation is created from the decimal representations
 of A and B as follows:

```
• the first (i.e. the most significant) digit of C is the first digit of A;
• the second digit of C is the first digit of B;
• the third digit of C is the second digit of A;
• the fourth digit of C is the second digit of B;
• etc.
```

If one of the integers A and B runs out of digits, the remaining digits of 
 the other integer are appended to the result.

The decimal representation of 0 is assumed to be "0".

For example, the decimal zip of 12 and 56 is 1526.
 The decimal zip of 56 and 12 is 5162.
 The decimal zip of 12345 and 678 is 16273845.
 The decimal zip of 123 and 67890 is 16273890.

Write a function: function solution(A, B); that, given two non-negative
 integers A and B, returns their decimal zip.

The function should return -1 if the result exceeds 100,000,000.

For example, given A = 12345 and B = 678 the function should return 
 16273845, as explained above.

I have seen many solutions using java but i was trying to find a solution for above problem using scala...

[**↓ Solution attempt in answer below ↓**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876115/2707792)

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Some hints: strings behave like sequences of characters (try e.g. `"abc".map(x => (x.toInt, x) )`). Have a look at the scaladoc of [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a maybe somewhat more idiomatic solution, which also takes the types of inputs as specified:

```
object Demo {

   def decimalZip(ai: Int, bi: Int): Int = {
      val a = ai.toString
      val b = bi.toString
      val m = a.size min b.size
      val resStr = (a zip b)
        .flatMap { case (x, y) => Seq(x, y) }
        .mkString + 
        a.drop(m) + 
        b.drop(m)

      Some(resStr)
        .filter(_.size <= 9)
        .map(_.toInt)
        .filter(_ <= 100000000)
        .getOrElse(-1)
   }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for ((a, b, res) <- List(
      (12, 56, 1526),
      (56, 12, 5162),
      (12345, 678, 16273845),
      (123, 67890, 16273890),
      (1111, 11111, -1)
    )) {
      val actualResult = decimalZip(a, b)
      require(res == actualResult)
      println(s"$a $b -> $actualResult")
    }
  }
}
```

prints:

```
12 56 -> 1526
56 12 -> 5162
12345 678 -> 16273845
123 67890 -> 16273890
1111 11111 -> -1
```

Alternatively, the `flatMap` could be replaced by

```
.map{ case (x, y) => new String(Array(x, y)) }
```

or

```
.map { case (x, y) => s"$x$y" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen a Python implementation yet..

```py
def zip(A, B):
    #Base case to break out prior to running.
    if A < 0 or B < 0 or A > 100000000 or B > 100000000:
        return -1
    else:
        C = ""
        count = 0
        Astr = str(A)
        Bstr = str(B)
        #Iterate through A
        for a in Astr:
            C += a
            #If values still remain in B
            if not count >= len(Bstr):
                C += Bstr[count]
                count += 1
        #If we are done with A, then we can continue with only B
        if count < len(Bstr):
            for b in range(count, len(Bstr)):
                C += Bstr[b]
        return C
```

Comment: You haven't seen a Python implementation because none was asked for. The OP specifically asks for a Scala solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       var a = 
      println( "Decimal Zip Value : " + decimalZip(123,56789) );
   }

   def decimalZip( aa:Long, ab:Long ) : Long = {
        var a=aa.toString;
        var b=ab.toString;
        if ((a.toLong < 0 || a.toLong > 100000000) || ((b.toLong < 0 || b.toLong > 100000000))) {
            return -1;
        }
      var i = 0;
      var c = ""
      while(i < a.length() || i < b.length() ){
            if (i < a.length()) {
                c += a.charAt(i);
            }
            if (i < b.length()) {
                c += b.charAt(i);
            }
        i+=1;
      }
      var result = c.toLong
       if (result > 100000000) {
            return -1;
        }
      return result
   }
}
```

Comment: Not idiomatic Scala. You're using the Scala language to write Java code.